# Overriding Zuul Filter SendErrorFilter

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

The class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter handles error responses.

I would like to override this filter to do a custom response instead of the ZuulException while forwarding etc.

How can I replace this with my own version?
Just write and register?  Would that do it or is there something else needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all you need to do is create a `ZuulFilter` and expose it as an `@Bean`.  It needs to be in order before `SendErrorFilter` which is set to `0`.  You might need to remove `"error.status_code"` from the `RequestContext` so SendErrorFilter doesn't run.

Comment: ok that makes sense.  I thought about putting it in advance order but wanted to know how to make sure that SendErrorFilter did not fire.  Thanks, that will do.

Comment: @EvilJinious1 were you able to get this done I have been trying to do this but i am unable to get it working... can you post your actual answer here,

Answer (score 6):

property name is changed to "**zuul.SendErrorFilter.error.disable**"

Comment: This does not seem to prevent bean creation of SendErrorFilter, does it?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to disable a default `SendErrorFilter` by adding `zuul.SendErrorFilter.post.disable: true` to your `application.properties`. After this you can create your own.