# Get microservices HTTP errors from JHipster API Gateway

Tags: spring, jhipster

I'm using a microservices architecture created via JHipster (Spring Boot, Zuul Proxy, Ribbon...). I have 2 microservices and a gateway (and of course a Registry).

I have a problem when sending HTTP errors from my microservices. The gateway seems to ignore the response from the microservice and generate a new response just using the error code.

Example :

My request generates a HTTP 404 in my microservice. If a request directly the microservice I have the following response body :

```
{
    "code": "DEVICE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "Gateway '12345678' unknown"
}
```

If I request the gateway (which transfer to the microservice), I now have the following body instead of the one generated by the service :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2016-08-11T12:50:57.432+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available"
}
```

The body from gateway does not contain any of the data from the licroservice error body...

If I understand, when the gateway get an error from a webcall, it calls a generated "/error" controller which create a response. I tried to implement my own /error controller by I was not able to get the original body. I also tried to add a @ControllerAdvice controller but no exception is returned in the gateway, it is just a redirect to the /error controller

Did I miss something ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@GaëlMarziou OK I found how it works.

There is a Zuul filter (org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter) that catches microservice response body and call the ErrorController to generate its own one. I created my one Zuul filter ([show the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152174/overriding-zuul-filter-senderrorfilter)) and overrided the whitelabel error controller ([solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page)) and I now have the response body of the microservice in my gateway.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, please consider proposing a pull request to JHipster project on github