# Spring Cloud Zuul - Custom Error Filter

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-zuul

I want to add a custom error Zuul Filter and want to make sure SendErrorFilter does not execute. I have looked at few github links including [Spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1874) and various *stack-overflow questions*:-

[Customizing Zuul Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461493/customizing-zuul-exception)

[Overriding Zuul Filter SendErrorFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152174/overriding-zuul-filter-senderrorfilter)

My code is as follows-

```
  public class CustomErrorFilter extends ZuulFilter {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomErrorFilter.class);

@Override
public String filterType() {
    return "post";
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return -1; 
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    RequestContext ctx=RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    if(ctx.getThrowable()!=null)
        return true;
    else
       return false;
}

@Override
public Object run() {

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

            ctx.setThrowable(null); // response is not returned unless 
                                      throwable is set to null.
            ctx.remove("error.status_code");

            ctx.setResponseBody(“Error”);
            ctx.getResponse().setContentType("text/plain");
            ctx.setResponseStatusCode(400);

    }

    return null;
}
```

I am having the following issues-

1. Setting filter order to `-1` does not prohibit `sendErrorFilter` from running.
2. To stop sendErrorFilter from running, I need to set 
   `zuul.SendErrorFilter.error.disable=true` in `bootstrap.yml`
3. To get a response body which is set in the custom error filter, i need to set `throwable` to `null` as mentioned in the [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1874).
4. Setting a filter as type **"error"** does nothing, and the custom filer does not run.

I would like someone to explain, what I am doing wrong and what is the most correct way of handling custom error filters, because there is lot of conflicting information available on the web.

**Dependencies-**

1. spring cloud - Edgware.RELEASE
2. spring cloud netflix starter zuul- 1.4.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`filtertype()` should return `"error"` if you want to handle error scenario

`filterOrder()` should be `-1` to execute before `SendErrorFilter`

Add the following lines to your filter(CustomErrorFilter )

```
protected static final String SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN = "sendErrorFilter.ran";
```

and

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    ctx.set(SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN);
    // rest of your code
    return null;
}
```

`ctx.set(SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN);` will block the `SendErrorFilter` from running.

---

Update:

Check `shouldFilter()` method in [SendErrorFilter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/post/SendErrorFilter.java)

```
@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    // only forward to errorPath if it hasn't been forwarded to already
    return ctx.getThrowable() != null
            && !ctx.getBoolean(SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN, false);
}
```

For every request a `RequestContext` gets created, but spring is not setting `SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN` in the context. May be for older version you have to configure from yaml file (`zuul.SendErrorFilter.error.disable=true`) for newer version(`1.4.3.RELEASE`) its from code like `ctx.set(SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN)`.

By default `!ctx.getBoolean(SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN, false)` this will evaluates to true and `run()` method of `SendErrorFilter` will execute.

if you put `ctx.set(SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN)` in your `CustomErrorFilter` with `filterOrder()` as -1, your `CustomErrorFilter` will execute first and we are setting the `RequestContext` with `SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN` as true. Now when it goes to `shouldFilter()` method of `SendErrorFilter` evaluate to false and it won't execute `run()` method of `SendErrorFilter`.

Comment: would this make the filter execute before sendError filter and also what is d right way to make sendError filter not execute?

Comment: Could u throw some light on what is happening behind the scenes when an error gets thrown, and why did ur suggested fix work?